# Unresolved external Vcl::Filectrl::SelectDirectory

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

I am using [`Vcl::Filectrl::SelectDirectory()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.FileCtrl.SelectDirectory) in C++ Builder 10.3.1 but I receive error:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Vcl::Filectrl::SelectDirectory(System::UnicodeString, System::WideString, System::UnicodeString&, System::Set<Vcl::Filectrl::TSelectDirExtOpt, 0, 5>, Vcl::Controls::TWinControl *)' referenced from
```

What library should I link to resolve the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ Builder 10.3.1, vclx.lib should be linked. Change the following line in the project file:

```
<AllPackageLibs>rtl.lib;vcl.lib;</AllPackageLibs>
```

to

```
<AllPackageLibs>rtl.lib;vcl.lib;vclx.lib</AllPackageLibs>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line to your C++ file:

```cpp
#pragma link "vclx.lib"
```